# How to deploy dll with resource files to sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

I have SharePoint 2013 project with additional library project. This library project has resource files in other languages. I am adding this library in my package as "additional assembly" but after deploy all resource (satellite) assemblies are not added to GAC. Is there any way to automate this?

The only way I know is to define post build action to copy this assembly to folder and add this assembly in package as external assembly. Do you know a better way?

Comment: How have you deployed it?

Comment: I have SharePoint farm soulution (wsp) and i am using powershell to deploy it

Comment: Is it correct that the satellite assemblies are strongly named?